# Files seem to be copying to iCloud Drive even though I've not tried to copy anything

Tags: macos, icloud, high-sierra

I opened my icloud drive and noticed a message at the bottom of the Finder window.  The message is shown in the following image.

[image]

The way I read this is that 7,546 files and folders totaling 6.29 GB are being written to my icloud drive. Is that correct? If so, why is this happening?

I am running High Sierra on my iMac.

Comment: Please edit your question and include what version of Mac OS X you're using. (Maybe also add it as a tag, i.e. mojave, catalina, etc.)

Comment: i have updated my question to cover both points you made.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has gotten ever-more-aggressive about activating iCloud-on-by-default as the years pass.

The most likely cause is that Desktop & Documents iCloud syncing is enabled in System Preferences --> iCloud.

Here are some screen shots, note that in my example I do **not** have Desktop & Documents syncing turned on.

[image]

---

[image]